# Dart: Can we fix all prefer_constant_constructors with some tool?

Tags: flutter, dart, constants

I added `prefer_const_constructors` linter rule to my `analysis_options.yaml` and it found over 500+ issues where `const` is missing in my project. Is there any tool that can fix all problems without doing it manually?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Try using this in your `.vscode/settings.json` to solve all lints of the file on saving